# How can I run some JS code every time some Ajax loads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Addon that runs a simple piece of JS code that resizes a div on a page. It works fine when the page loads. However, the site using some ajax. When the ajax loads, the div resize gets undone. How can I get the script to re-execute everytime this ajax request loads?

The ajax always simply loads from just one place everytime: www.website.com/Default.aspx

This is probably really simple, but I'm a complete and total novice at this :) Thank you!

---

In regards to the request to see the code, keep in mind I have no real programming experience beyond an understanding of fundamental principles. This addon has been scrapped together from Google searches and such. Maybe I've bitten off more than I can chew, but here goes:

This is the code that gets executed:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_Body_cntrl_rgMyIssues_GridData').style.height = '500px';
```

This is the part of the manifest.json that deals with running the js:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://www.website.com/*"],
  "js": ["resize_queue.js"]
 }
],
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I've added the `google-chrome-extension` tag, since you **can't** do this in a cross-browser way, but since you say you're doing an add-on, it may be that there's some Chrome-specific thing you can do.

Comment: Is it possible to not use fixed units, but relative units (or [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc))? Then your problem becomes easier to solve. Otherwise, it might actually be a better idea to listen for changes of the element's content (using [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)s) instead of AJAX requests.

Answer (score -2):

If you're just looking to do a piece of javascript code after your ajax request comes back, you could do it one of two ways basically.

1) Do a synchronous instead of asynchronous request.

This is a simple as this: `xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false); //Note the false`

Then you just put whatever code you want to run after this, and javascript will wait to do it until after the ajax request is complete.

2) Put the code you want to run in the readystate part of the ajax.

The following is taken from w3schools (which isn't as terrible as everyone says):

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    //Do other code here
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: The OP has no control over the construction of the AJAX request. Between the lines in the question, you can see that the OP is running code on some third-party site. Also, come on, don't copy-paste "code for IE6, IE5" from W3schools... What are the odds of reaching that if-branch in a Chrome extension?

Comment: I took it from w3schools cause it's pointless to rewrite it when it's already there, and I was just demonstrating an example.

Also, this answer is for generic Ajax.  If Chrome extensions requires the use of some exclusive api that you have to go through and you can't even change the parameters of your own ajax request then I don't know how to help.